# Django migration: only part of the model successfully migrated to sql

Tags: python, django, migration

Please see my models and forms.(Python 2.7). After running python manage.py migrate, only "company" and "region" successfully appear in the database.

**Error showing**: type error expected string or buffer

I used to try add manually the columns in the database, but then the form's data cannot be saved to database.

Please help pinpoint the causes of this migration issue. Thanks in advance for any help.

**models.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.db import models
from dupont.models import Result
from datetime import date
from django.forms import widgets

class Input(models.Model):
    company=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    region=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    supply_chain=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    uom=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_date=models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    end_date=models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.company
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Input
from dupont.models import Result
from django.contrib.auth.models import User,Group
from datetimewidget.widgets import DateTimeWidget, DateWidget, TimeWidget
from django.forms import widgets
from functools import partial
from django.forms.util import ErrorList

DateInput = partial(forms.DateInput, {'class': 'datepicker'})

class InputForm(forms.ModelForm):
    company=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput, label="Company",error_messages={'required': 'Please enter the company name'},required=True)
    regionlist = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Result.objects.values('region').distinct())
    sc_list=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Result.objects.values('supply_chain').distinct())
    uom=forms.CharField(required=True)
    start_date=forms.DateField(widget=DateInput())
    end_date = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput())
    error_css_class='error'
    required_css_class = 'required'


    class Meta:
        model = Input
        fields = ('company', 'region','supply_chain','uom','start_date','end_date')
        widgets = {
            'start_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}),
            'end_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}),
        }
```

**error**

```
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\core\managem
ent\__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\core\managem
ent\__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\core\managem
ent\base.py", line 393, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\core\managem
ent\base.py", line 444, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\core\managem
ent\commands\migrate.py", line 221, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\db\migration
s\executor.py", line 110, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(states[migration], migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=f
ake_initial)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\db\migration
s\executor.py", line 148, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\db\migration
s\migration.py", line 115, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, projec
t_state)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\db\migration
s\operations\fields.py", line 62, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\db\backends\
mysql\schema.py", line 43, in add_field
    super(DatabaseSchemaEditor, self).add_field(model, field)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\db\backends\
base\schema.py", line 384, in add_field
    definition, params = self.column_sql(model, field, include_default=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\db\backends\
base\schema.py", line 146, in column_sql
    default_value = self.effective_default(field)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\db\backends\
base\schema.py", line 211, in effective_default
    default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\fi
elds\__init__.py", line 710, in get_db_prep_save
    prepared=False)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\fi
elds\__init__.py", line 1322, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\fi
elds\__init__.py", line 1317, in get_prep_value
    return self.to_python(value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\fi
elds\__init__.py", line 1274, in to_python
    parsed = parse_date(value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\utils\datepa
rse.py", line 60, in parse_date
    match = date_re.match(value)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should check your `form's data`, looks like they are not the right date data.

Comment: Thank you. I delete the schema and migration file in the app. Also delete the "auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False" in the datefield. And re-run the syncdb code. Then it works now.